# WPF SplashScreen for Sql connection

Tags: wpf

In my WPF app I have to connect to a remote server and retrieve/send some data.

I would like a splash screen to show during the connection and communication process and that would show a "Cancel action" after a certain amount of time has passed and no result has been produced.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction... I was thinking about going by thread monitor, but my app is quite simple and small and I don't want to waste time on something so complex. If there's an easy answer I'd appreciate it Smile | :)

NOTE: Forget about the idea of creating a user control or window with a simple show or showdialog. It doesn't work. If the connection fails (wich at my home happens quite often) the whole app gets frozen, and even the user control or window that I used as splash screen is accessible. The same goes for SqlCommand.StatementCompleted event, it has the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind or ViewModel, create an `IsBusy` flag that raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event when changed.

After set a time of activity, set this flag to true (this can be done with a `Timer` instance).

In your XAML, bind a control (`Grid` for example) to be visible only when the flag is set.

In this control, have a cancel button that is bound to a command (or `Click` event) that does what it needs to do.

Comment: Oh. I posted this answer before your edit. This may not be what you're looking for after-all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the background worker for this.

```
1)  Load your splash screen
2)  Kick off background worker to retrieve data (handle timeouts, errors in this method)
3)  In your background worker completed event -close your splash screen (or display errors, etc)
```